# Firefox pages all blank with white spinning circle after suspend/resume 16.04 LTS

Tags: firefox, suspend

A few weeks ago, i noticed everytime i suspend or close my laptop, all my active pages in firefox are now blank with a white spinning circle.

Refreshing the page does nothing.  I've noticed a process running called "Web Content"  and if i kill it then Firefox and all my tabs remain, but say they've crashed and I have to reload them.

This has been my workaround for a while, but its pretty annoying, even short trips away from my laptop cause this (if i have to close the laptop)

Comment: Closing/opening (Suspend/Resume) your laptop executes several scripts to fix hardware (save/restore state, reinitialize, whatever). One of these scripts is mishandling your WiFi card, and upon resume, you have no/bad connection. Read `man pm-action`

Comment: See https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/67en47/firefox_occasionally_gets_stuck_loading_pages/
and
https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/5e41vn/whats_with_the_spinning_wheel/. The issue is with the multiprocess feature and add-on compatibility most probably.